# Bootstrapping in SPSS

Tags: syntax, spss, statistics-bootstrap

I was wondering if there was a work around for bootstrapping in SPSS? My license for SPSS doesn't have the boostrap module installed.

I have also tried on R as well. I am not sure about the syntax for R bootstrapping as sources online give varying ways to bootstrap.

Comment: In SPSS you can always just draw the bootstrap samples yourself, then use SPLIT FILE and OMS. What procedure do you want to bootstrap?

Comment: I want to bootstrap the list of means (which is a variable). I would like to bootstrap frequencies and linear regression. I am not sure how to do the SPSS syntax without bootstrap module installed.

Comment: Do you have access to the CNLR command? That can do the bootstrapping for you for linear regression. If you want means you can just estimate an intercept for the linear regression.

Comment: I do. How do I draw the bootstrap samples myself? I have 1249 total cases and want 100 bootstrapped samples.  I want to start off with the frequencies. Sample

Comment: I attempted some syntax to get boostrapped samples.   I am not sure if this is correct.                                                                                                   LOOP SAMP=1 to 100.
LOOP V = 1 to 1269.
Compute ID=TRUNC(UNIFORM(1269)) +1
END CASE.
LEAVE SAMP.
END LOOP.
END LOOP.